# Search and extract specific string start with and end with specific string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
txt = ''' lea_po () {
val : 96.9;
wh : "CP D ";
related : DD;
leak () {
va : 0.008;
when : " SI";
in : V;
}
**stagestat (" E  I       P", "I  2 ") {
data : "  H  H/L   -    R  :  -    -    - : L   -    - , \
               -       :  -    -    - : L   -    - , \
           -   -    -    R  :   -    - :  -      - , \
           -   -    -      :  -    - :  -    -   L, \
           -   -    -   ~R  :  -    -    - :  N    P    N ";
}**
...
'''
```

I would like to only extract the bold part which start with the `stagestat` and end with the curly bracket `"}"`.
But I tried to use a python regex to search but it fails.

```
re.search("^stagestat.*}$",txt)
```

Can someone give some comments on this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```py
re.findall('(?<=stagestat)(.*?)(?=})', txt, flags=re.S)
```

Output - a list containing all matches between [`stagestat` and `}`]:

```
[' (" E  I       P", "I  2 ") {\ndata : "  H  H/L   -    R  :  -    -    - : L   -    - ,                -       :  -    -    - : L   -    - ,            -   -    -    R  :   -    - :  -      - ,            -   -    -      :  -    - :  -    -   L,            -   -    -   ~R  :  -    -    - :  N    P    N ";\n']
```

Comment: To add to this: regex by default only check line-by-line, meaning the `$` in the question looked for a `}` on the same line. One could precompile the pattern using `re.compile(r"pattern", re.MULTILINE)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multi-line mode (for making `^` match the beginning of the line, not of the whole string) and single line mode (for making `.` match also newlines):

```
re.search("^stagestat.*}$", txt, flags = re.S | re. M)
```

Also, consider using `.*?` (for matching as less character as possible) or equivalently `[^}]*` (for stopping at the very first closed curly bracket) instead of `}$`.